# Find the equilibrium point and its variance in stochastic data?

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have some data of the form [image: stochastic process]

I need to find the point where it starts reaching equilibrium (as I can see from the graph around 1000 iteration) and how much fluctuating the data points are. Is there a function to do that? I have been playing around with autocorrelation but nothing works.

Any guidance/readings suggestion is truly appreciated.

DISCLAIMER: I have zero to minimum background in statistics but I have been asked to present my data that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to construct a model for these data, estimate parameters for the model, and extract the equilibrium level from that. E.g. a possible model is `y = y0 * (1 - exp(t/T)) + epsilon` where `y0` is the equilibrium level, `T` is a time scaling factor, and `epsilon` is (let's say) Gaussian noise. Given some data, estimate `y0` and `T`, and estimate the standard deviation of `epsilon` as the RMS of the residuals. The magnitude of the "fluctuating around" is then the standard deviation of `epsilon`.

There are many possible models, and which you should pick depends on your goals. Take a look at Seber & Wild, "Nonlinear Regression".

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you several methods but must use some kind of algorithm for it, because there is an specific need.

- You can make an analysis using intervals of samples an measure how change the variance. Cause the variance is a dispersion measurement, and according to the samples their seems to be relative stable after a while,  you can take the interval in wich the variance stops to fall. Let say take **intervals** of 100 samples, computes their **variance** in each step and stop in the **interval** in which the computed variance is greater than the **half of the previous one**. (of course you can made more intensive search and do not take the half of the previuos variance as stop point or take more or less than 100 samples. That will depends of your experiment or your data).
- You can also try to apply a **function analysis** approch. making a m**oving average filter** of small points (say 5 or 10) and in that way **smooth** the curve, then you can analyse their **derivative** and try to get the point when is closer to 0 (similiar to a rect. after sample 1000 more or less)